# User not logged in into phpbb with Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, phpbb3

I have a existing Yii2 application.

So in this application I have successfully install phpbb. But when I am trying to login from my site then it will not logged in this user in phpbb-forum. I am not getting the user identity. I am also not getting the **password_reg** into afterLogin() method. So phpbb-forum authentication not working.

Below is my snippets :

**PhpBBWebUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace nill\forum;

use Yii;
use yii\web\User;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;

class PhpBBWebUser extends User {

    /** @var UserIdentity */
    private $_identity;

    public function login(IdentityInterface $identity, $duration = 0) {
        $this->_identity = $identity;
        return parent::login($identity, $duration);
    }

    protected function afterLogin($identity, $fromCookie, $duration) {
        if ($this->_identity !== null) {
            if (\Yii::$app->phpBB->login($this->_identity->username, $this->_identity->password_reg) != 'SUCCESS') {
                throw new InvalidParamException('PhpBB Authentication failed!');
            }
        }

        parent::afterLogin($identity, $fromCookie, $duration);
    }

    protected function afterLogout($identity) {
        \Yii::$app->phpBB->logout();
        parent::afterLogout($identity);
    }

}
```

**Model -> Users.php**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use common\components\Common;
use nill\forum\models\phpBBUsers;
use nill\forum\behaviors\PhpBBUserBahavior;



class Users extends \common\models\base\UsersBase implements IdentityInterface
{
    public $user_role;
    public $password_new;
    public $password_reg;

    /**
     * Behavior PhpBBUserBahavior necessary for integration with the forum
     */
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'PhpBBUserBahavior' => [
                'class'       => PhpBBUserBahavior::className(),
                'userAttr'    => 'username',
                'newpassAttr' => 'password_new',
                'passAttr'    => 'password',
                'emailAttr'   => 'email',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password     = md5($password);
    }

     /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return $this->password === md5($password);
    }

    public function getPhpbbuser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(phpBBUsers::className(), ['username' => 'username']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say. Any logs? Have you followed instructions at https://github.com/8sun/yii2-integration-phpBB3.1 ?

Comment: Yes I am following [above link](http://github.com/8sun/yii2-integration-phpBB3.1) instruction.

Comment: How I can get the password_reg in PhpBBWebuser's after login?

Comment: Well, in the instruction this is set inside the `validatePassword` method (Part 4).

Comment: Yes. But my old code is                                                                                      `public function validatePassword($password) {
        return $this->password === md5($password);
    }`

Comment: So if I change my validatepassword() acording to part-4 then it will work with my site login? Can you please tell me the validatepassword() method definition?

Comment: I don't know if it will work. This method's definition depends on your application (it's not part of any interface). Looks like it is used just like in Yii 2 Advanced Template project and author just adds there password_reg setter. Also - don't use md5() for passwords if you care about the security.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124866/discussion-between-sanjay-chaudhari-and-bizley).